# Ошибки при запуске html с помощью eel

Tags: python, html, http, eel

Написал небольшую веб-страничку для отслеживания погоды. html, css, js и логика на python. Запускать это всё через отдельный файл с кодом:

```
import eel
from middle_weather import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eel.init('web')
    eel.start('weather.html')
```

При запуске файла выходит такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

порт 8000 (стандарт eel) занят httpd, если менять порт, то ошибка 404

Пытался дать разрешения для httpd.exe на обычного пользователя и т.д., менять на свободные порты (как уже говорил, ошибка 404), переустанавливал PyCharm. Если запускать html файл отдельно, то работает